Why are different operations in mathematics referred to as "convolution"?
Convolution appears in many mathematical contexts, such as signal processing, probability, and harmonic analysis. Each context seems to involve slightly different formulas and operations:

In standard convolution (e.g., in signal processing and Fourier analysis), we integrate the product of a function and a flipped-shifted version of another function over the entire real line, with limits $-\infty$ to $\infty$.
In Laplace convolution, the integrand is similar; but the integral is evaluated over $[0,t]$ ($t$ is shifting parameter).
In circular convolution, again the integrand is similar unless integral can be evaluated over any interval of length $\tau$ (the period).
In Mellin convolution, one function is scaled before being multiplied by the other, and then integrated over positive values.

As you can see, the details of the operations differ, but they all share the name "convolution."
This raises my question

What is the unifying mathematical concept that links these different types of convolutions?
Is there a deep reason or shared insight that justifies giving these operations the same name?

Note: Before encountering the Mellin transform, I thought the core idea of convolution was "flipping, shifting, and blending two functions over an interval." Although this pattern differs slightly across contexts, Mellin convolution seems to deviate from it entirely.
I’m particularly interested in understanding this from a conceptual perspective:

Are they all instances of a more abstract operation?
How do their similarities and differences relate to their domains (time, scale, frequency, etc.)?

I’d appreciate answers that explore the core mathematical principles or structures behind the term "convolution." Thank you!

See also Dirichlet convolution in analytic number theory. The wikipedia article on convolution gives a nice survey, and might be helpful for you.

There is also Day convolution that doesn't involve numbers or intervals at all!

There's also the convolution of two densities ( in probability ) which doesn't involve flipping. I don't know what the general rule is for the use of the term "convolution".

Unless someone can cite a counterexample, I'd say a convolution $\star$ is associated with an operator $O$ (likely a linear or antilinear one) viz. $(Of)(Og)=O(f\star g)$.

Fourier and Mellin convolution are related as are the Fourier and Mellin transforms (each can be expressed in terms of the other). The identities for Fourier and Mellin convolution are $\delta(x)$ and $\delta(x−1)$ respectively. The Fourier and Mellin transforms are also related to the bilateral Laplace transform.

See this for an intuitive explanation for what a convolution is. This makes a lot more sense to me than non-abelian groups or operators with certain properties.

@JohnDouma: I liked that explanation. Thanks for sharing

The general frame is the harmonic analysis on locally compact commutative groups.  (Convolution exists also for non commutative groups, but things are more involved). For instance Mellin transform deals with the multiplicative group  of positive numbers. You could try to have a look on the first two chapters of Rudin 1963 'Fourier Analysis on Groups' which exists in Dover.

Based on your meta-post about the level of answer you're looking for, I'll add a more intuitive answer, one that is less precise but lower level. Please take all the terms below very roughly:
I don't know all the examples you've listed, but when I see the term convolution I expect to see

two indexed sets of numbers, or functions (which are just sets of numbers that are indexed by a real number),

producing a new indexed set by summing up a bunch of terms that come from multiplying terms taken from the two indexed sets,

and which terms are multiplied together depends on some (algebraic) connection between the indices. "Add up to the same thing" for $f(u-t)g(t)$, or "agree in one component" for $K(u,t)g(t)$.


Because this can get quite generic, you might see addition replaced with multiplication, or even some general, unspecified group operation, but those are the common elements that correspond to the "bilaterally symmetric with a spine" that we often expect to see when we hear the word "animal".
(A good motivation for understanding this can be found in "group rings", but sadly the Wikipedia article for that subject comes in at "highly abstract", and doesn't seem to work out any of the simple examples I've seen elsewhere.)

All cited examples are deeply connected. Let us start with the convolution on $\mathbb R$, defined as
$$
f\ast g(t):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-s)g(s)\, ds.$$
If we replace $f$ and $g$ with $f\mathbf 1_{[0, \infty)}$ and $g\mathbf 1_{[0, \infty)}$, we get
$$
f\mathbf 1_{[0, \infty)}\ast g\mathbf 1_{[0, \infty)} (t)=\int_0^t f(t-s)g(s)\, ds, $$
which is the Laplace convolution.
Conclusion: The Laplace convolution is just a special case of the ordinary convolution. It arises when considering functions supported in $[0, \infty)$.
Now let us perform the changes of variable
$$
\tau=e^t,\quad \sigma=e^s,\quad F(\tau)=f(t),\quad G(\sigma)=g(s).
$$
The convolution $f\ast g(t)$ becomes
$$
\int_{0}^\infty F(\tau\sigma^{-1})G(\sigma)\frac{d\sigma}{\sigma}, $$
which is the Mellin convolution of $F$ and $G$, evaluated at $\tau$.
Conclusion: The Mellin convolution is exactly the same as the ordinary convolution up to the map $t\in \mathbb R\mapsto \tau=e^t\in \mathbb R_{>0}$, which is a group isomorphism of $(\mathbb R, +)$ onto $(\mathbb R_{>0}, \cdot)$. This is not a coincidence as pointed out in the other answers.
Finally, we turn to the convolution on the circle, that is
$$
f\ast_{\mathbb T^1} g(\theta)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(\theta-\rho)g(\rho)\, d\rho.$$
This is also a special case of the ordinary convolution on $\mathbb R$, provided $f$ is considered as a $2\pi$-periodic function and $g$ is supported in $[-\pi, \pi]$.
Final note. This is not how the circle convolution arose in the first place. The circle convolution is tied to the group structure of $\mathbb T^1=(\mathbb R / 2\pi\mathbb Z, +)$, which is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb R, +)$. It still is a quotient of it, though, which is a qualitative reason why we could recover the circle convolution from the ordinary one.
(Note that $\mathbb T^1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^\times= \{ \chi\in\mathbb C, \lvert\chi\rvert=1\}$, the operation being complex multiplication).
